# How may I show that for $r>0$, it is linearly unstable and for $0<r<1$ it is nonlinearly stable?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> For the $C^1$  systems of equations $x'=-|x|^rx, y'=x,r>0$, show by direct calculation that the equilibrium $(0,0)$ is linearly unstable for all $r>0$, but nonlinearly unstable precisely for $r\geq 1$.

My Work:

Case I: $r\geq 1$.

So the system is $  \left( \begin{array}{c}
x \\y \end{array} \right)'=f(x,y)=\left( \begin{array}{c}
-|x|^rx \\x  \end{array} \right)= \left( \begin{array}{cc}
-|x|^r & 0 \\
1 & 0 \end{array} \right)\left( \begin{array}{c}
x \\y \end{array} \right)$.

Let $A=\left( \begin{array}{cc}
-|x|^r & 0 \\
1 & 0 \end{array} \right)$.

So, at the eqilibrium $(0,0)$, $A= \left( \begin{array}{cc}
0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 \end{array} \right)$. The eigenvalue of $A$ is $0$ and it is not semisimple. Hence, $(0,0)$ is nonlinearly unstable for $r\geq 1$.
But how may I show that for $r>0$, it is linearly unstable and for $0<r<1$ it is nonlinearly stable? I am so confused because I don't see any difference between the cases where $r>0$ and $r\geq 1$, since both make $-|x|^r$ to $0$ at $(0,0)$. Can anybody please tell me how to figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint.**

For nonlinear stability, also just called stability, you have to find the solutions of the complete systems of equation. Then you have to see if for all $\epsilon >0$, you can find $\delta >0$ such that for $\Vert (x_0,y_0) \Vert < \delta$ you have $$\Vert (x(t), y(t))\Vert < \epsilon$$ for all $t$ where the solution is defined with the initial condition $(x(0),y(0)) =(x_0,y_0)$.

Comment: So, how do I find solutions here? It seems complicated.

Comment: For $x_0 > 0$, you have around $t=0$: $-\frac{dx}{x^{r+1}}=dt$ hence $\frac{1}{x^r} - \frac{1}{x_0^r} = rt$. From there you can also find $y$.